# NimbusAPI response is timing out, though it says it was received

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm using [NimbusAPI](http://nimbusapi.github.io) working with Azure Service Bus.  I'm having trouble getting the response from a request/response action using Nimbus.  Below is the output of a unit test.  I can successfully get the request, step through it in a breakpoint, and watch it return a response.  The client, whether the unit test, an MVC app, or anything else, always times out.  The second to last line in the output below shows that a response is actually received, but the last line says that it wasn't, and has timed out.

```
 12/17/2014 9:42:07 PM -05:00: Constructing bus... 12/17/2014 9:42:08
 PM -05:00: Creating message pumps and subscriptions.
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.RequestResponse.ResponseMessagePumpFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.RequestResponse.ResponseMessagePumpFactory)
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.MessageSendersAndReceivers.NimbusQueueMessageReceiver
 (inputqueue.myapp.mypc) Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.MessagePump (Nimbus.Infrastructure.MessagePump)
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.NimbusMessagingFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.NimbusMessagingFactory) Nimbus.GarbageMan:
 Tracking Nimbus.Infrastructure.Commands.CommandMessagePumpsFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.Commands.CommandMessagePumpsFactory) 12/17/2014
 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Creating command message pumps Nimbus.GarbageMan:
 Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.RequestResponse.RequestMessagePumpsFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.RequestResponse.RequestMessagePumpsFactory)
 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Creating request message pumps
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.RequestResponse.MulticastRequestMessagePumpsFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.RequestResponse.MulticastRequestMessagePumpsFactory)
 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Creating multicast request message pumps
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.Events.MulticastEventMessagePumpsFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.Events.MulticastEventMessagePumpsFactory)
 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Creating multicast event message pumps
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.Events.CompetingEventMessagePumpsFactory
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.Events.CompetingEventMessagePumpsFactory)
 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Creating competing event message pumps
 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Message pumps and subscriptions are all
 created. 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Bus built. Job done!
 Nimbus.GarbageMan: Tracking
 Nimbus.Infrastructure.MessageSendersAndReceivers.NimbusQueueMessageSender
 (Nimbus.Infrastructure.MessageSendersAndReceivers.NimbusQueueMessageSender)
 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Sending request
 Myapp.Messages.DoItRequest to
 q.myapp.messages.doitrequest
 [MessageId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8,
 CorrelationId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8] 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM
 -05:00: Sent request Myapp.Messages.DoItRequest to q.myapp.messages.doitrequest
 [MessageId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8,
 CorrelationId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8] 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM
 -05:00: Waiting for response to Myapp.Messages.DoItRequest from
 q.myapp.messages.doitrequest
 [MessageId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8,
 CorrelationId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8] 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM
 -05:00: Flushing outbound message queue q.myapp.messages.doitrequest (1 messages) 12/17/2014
 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Received response to
 Myapp.Messages.DoItRequest from
 q.myapp.messages.doitrequest
 [MessageId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8,
 CorrelationId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8] in the form of
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Myapp.Messages.DoItResponse,
 Myapp.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=null]] 12/17/2014 9:42:08 PM -05:00: Fetching existing
 queues... System.TimeoutException : No response was received from the
 bus within the configured timeout. Expected a
 'Myapp.Messages.DoItResponse'.
```

It says I got a response...

```
9:42:08 PM -05:00: **Received response to
  Myapp.Messages.DoItRequest from
  q.myapp.messages.doitrequest**
  [MessageId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8,
  CorrelationId:bc1c79cc1965489c84703f5898bd6fd8] **in the form of
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Myapp.Messages.DoItResponse**,
  Myapp.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=null]] 12/17/2014
```

Except that I didn't

```
9:42:08 PM -05:00: Fetching existing
queues... System.TimeoutException : **No response was received from the
bus within the configured timeout. Expected a
'Myapp.Messages.DoItResponse'.**
```

Is there something I'm missing that I need to check?

Comment: You should learn SO formatting.

Comment: I tried bolding the lines inside the code block, but that doesn't work, which is why I moved them out to separate text to just bold the "english" lines to make them more readable.  Sorry if I screwed it up, and thanks for editing and fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh. My. Gosh.

It seems that I failed to call `bus.Start();` to actually start the bus.  I created/configured the bus, which seems like it's enough to *send* messages, however `.Start();` is obviously required to actually subscribe and watch for the response to come back.  This explains why I could break on the back-end and see the response being created, and even see the message in the queue coming back, but the actual request timing out from the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be because of the synchronization context of the calling thread.

To see what the synchronization context is, set a watch on

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext.SynchronizationContext
```

If it's not null then it's likely that you have a deadlock (see link to article below).

If you have a test case that looks something like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task WhenSendingARequestWeShouldReceiveAResponse()
{
    var result = await _bus.Request(new SomeRequest());
    result.ShouldBeOfType<SomeResponse>();
}
```

then try replacing it with this:

```
[Test]
public async Task WhenSendingARequestWeShouldReceiveAResponse()
{
    var result = await _bus.Request(new SomeRequest()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    result.ShouldBeOfType<SomeResponse>();
}
```

or this:

```
[Test]
public Task WhenSendingARequestWeShouldReceiveAResponse()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var result = await _bus.Request(new SomeRequest());
        result.ShouldBeOfType<SomeResponse>();
    }
}
```

That will help you work out whether you're hitting a deadlock or another issue.

For more reading on synchronization contexts, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx. As an aside, anywhere you're calling .Wait() on a method that returns a Task or Task is asking for trouble.

Comment: I should add that we're working to make Nimbus avoid these kinds of issues on callers' behalves. It's not as simple as it sounds :)

Comment: Yea, there's definitely a lot to juggle. I changed the tests to add .ConfigureAwait(false) with the same result. It also looks like I asked for trouble. The handlers are part of a windows service that I'm starting up by using: Task.Run(() => MyWinService.MainAsync()).Wait();

Comment: SynchronizationContext stays null from the client's perspective that I see.  Checking the handler now.

Comment: The handling app's logs show a correlation ID that matches the request in the test "Completed message Myapp.Messages.DoItRequest from inputqueue.myapp.mycomputer"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `Environment.MachineName` to create unique instance names per the docs but forgot to change it during local end-to-end testing. Turns out the machine name is the same for two executables running on the same machine—who knew?

```
var bus = new BusBuilder().Configure()
    .WithNames("MyApplication", Environment.MachineName) // <-- Problem if running multiple instances on the same machine
```